# Listing IDs that match values in two columns of a table

Tags: query, sqlite

I'm using SQLite 3.27.2-3 on Debian Buster/stable. I could use some other DB, but for my use case (LuaTeX), something with low overhead seems to make sense.

My use case is that I have a letter (in the sense of correspondence) which refers to other letters in the text. I have a table that is automatically built from references in the text.

Let's say the table looks like this

```
RowID           From     To
=====           ====     ==
2019.06.05       PC      SW
2019.06.11       PC      SB
2019.06.12
2019.06.15       SB      PC
2019.06.22       DO      SW
```

and that it corresponds to some rows from a larger table, which I'll call `attachments`.

And let's suppose there is an abbreviations table which looks like

```
Abbreviation     Name
============     ====
B                Bashful
D                Dopey
DO               Doc
H                Happy
G                Grumpy
PC               Prince Charming
SB               Sleeping Beauty
S                Sleepy
SN               Sneezy
```

Then I want a table (`abbreviations`) that has a list of the abbreviations that occur in my short list of correspondence. This would look like

```
Abbreviation     Name
============     ====
DO               Doc
PC               Prince Charming
SB               Sleeping Beauty
SW               Snow White
```

Something like the query below works, approximately. But I also get blank output for when it doesn't match. I'm getting errors from SQLite (or LuaSQL, to be precise) so I'm wondering if it is because of the
blank output.

Better (and simpler) approaches appreciated.

```
SELECT abbreviations.Abbreviation,
       abbreviations.Name
FROM attachments
LEFT OUTER JOIN abbreviations ON attachments.`From`=abbreviations.Abbreviation
WHERE attachments.RowID IN ('2019.06.05',
                            '2019.06.11',
                            '2019.06.12',
                            '2019.06.15',
                            '2019.06.22')
UNION
SELECT abbreviations.Abbreviation,
       abbreviations.Name
FROM attachments
LEFT OUTER JOIN abbreviations ON attachments.`To`=abbreviations.Abbreviation
WHERE attachments.RowID IN ('2019.06.05',
                            '2019.06.11',
                            '2019.06.12',
                            '2019.06.15',
                            '2019.06.22');
```

Comment: Please offer suggestions for a better title. I don't think mine is particularly good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT abbreviations.*
FROM attachments
JOIN abbreviations ON abbreviations.Abbreviation IN (attachments.`To`, attachments.`From`)
WHERE attachments.RowID IN ('2019.06.05',
                            '2019.06.11',
                            '2019.06.12',
                            '2019.06.15',
                            '2019.06.22');
```

?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This appears to work - at least it gives the right answer for the example on hand. Can you elaborate a bit on the answer. I'm not familiar with the syntax used. And what kind of JOIN is this?

Comment: @FaheemMitha 1) You use left outer join. But you need only abbrevs which exists in both tables - so inner join needed. 2) You use union - 1st query joins by eq to `from` and 2nd by eq to `to`. I use one join by eq to `from` or `to` (`a IN (b,c)` eq `a=b OR a=c`).